# Where is a good place to put a few small utility functions in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a very small number of functions that I need to use like this:

```
data-ng-disabled="_isEmpty(grid.view) || view != 'preview'"
```

What I did was:

```
$scope._isEmpty = _.isEmpty;
```

so that the _isEmpty is actually the lodash function.

Is this a reasonable thing to do? Also if so then where would be a good place for me
to code the above line? Should I code that in my appController. Also should I attach
the ._isEmpty to $scope or $rootscope? I have heard people talking about making a service and then injecting this. But for a few lines of code this seems overkill.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add some small utility functions to my AngularJS application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614545/how-can-i-add-some-small-utility-functions-to-my-angularjs-application)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Though generally not recommended, I could see this kind of problem solved with putting the functions into the rootscope. Then putting the line `$scope._isEmpty = _.isEmpty;` in every controller would not be necessary anymore. A far better way for me would be to recode the utility functions into directives, even if involves some coding. Another way to solve the problem is to use services.

Comment: If I code into the top most controller then is that function not available to all the other controllers below that ?

Comment: Yes it is (except for isolate scope in directives). And there is an implictly created topmost controller for the application (besides your defined controllers) that has $rootsCope as its scope. Scopes are prototypically inherited in angulars.

Answer (score 16):

It all depends on where this code is required. If it is heavily reliant on, or required by a particular data object or view, then it most likely belongs in a controller. If inside a controller, `$scope` should be used by any value you want to reference in a view.

If however, you are writing generic functions used throughout your application, then they should be put in something like a service, and injected where required. Most of the time if you find yourself using `$rootScope`, the code should probably be in a service. Services aren't really overkill, as you can see below:

```
angular.module('myapp.services.something', [])
    .factory('myService', [function () {
        return {
            myFunc: function (someArg) {
                console.log(someArg);
            }
        };
     }]);
```

You could put any number of generic helper functions for example in a service like this, and inject them into any controller that requires their use.

Comment: Thank you for this, perfect solution in my situation. Also IMO the cleanest, most Angular-standards-compliant one.